# PHP XML Float Dividing

Tags: php, xml

I need parse this xml:

```
<ValCurs Date="25.04.2017" name="Foreign Currency Market">
<Valute ID="R01010">
<NumCode>036</NumCode>
<CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>AU Dollar</Name>
<Value>42,4465</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="R01060">
<NumCode>051</NumCode>
<CharCode>AMD</CharCode>
<Nominal>100</Nominal>
<Name>AM dram</Name>
<Value>11,5747</Value>
</Valute>
```

...

Have next code:

```
$file = simplexml_load_file($link);    
foreach ($file as $el) {
        (float)$rates=(float)($el->Value)/(float)($el->Nominal);
        echo (float)($el->Value) . '/' .(float)($el->Nominal) . '=' . $rates;         
    }
```

This code return:

> 32/1=32 71/1=71 11/100=0.11 29/1=29 31/1=31 17/1=17 19/100=0.19
>   72/10=7.2 81/10=8.1 56/1=56 60/1=60 87/100=0.87

But i need:
42,4465/1=42,4465 11,5747/100=0,115747
How to do it? )

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli) ( NTS )
```

Comment: replace comma (,) with dot (.)

Answer (score 1):

No need to cast the needed elements to `float` type twice.
Use the following approach:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($link);
foreach ($sxe as $el) {
    echo "{$el->Value}/{$el->Nominal}" . "=" 
         . bcdiv(str_replace(',', '.', $el->Value), $el->Nominal, 6) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

The output:

```
42,4465/1=42.446500
11,5747/100=0.115747
```

---

Used function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php

Comment: Thx for answer. I need output forexample: 42,4465/1=42,4465